# Can $\ln(x)$ be defined without integral calculus?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, logarithms

Typically, the natural log function is defined in integral calculus as $\ln(x)=\displaystyle\int_1^x \frac{dt}{t}$. Is it possible to define $\ln(x)$ using only differentiable calculus?

I should specify, I am asking this question while in an analysis class, where we are rigorously defining $\ln(x)$. We have no knowledge of $e^x$ to call $\ln(x)$ its inverse.

Comment: If you buy that $\exp:\mathbb{R}\to(0,\infty)$, $\exp(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty}(1+x/n)^n$ is a bijection (onto isn't bad and 1-1 follows from the fact that it's increasing), you could define $\ln$ as the functional inverse of $\exp$.

Comment: "Typically"... *where*? I can hardly remember one place that did that...and only after it was defined the usual way: as the logarithm in base $\;e\;$ , or in some cases as the inverse function of $\;e^x\;$ .

Comment: You could just introduce $\ln$ as an infinite series, and this avoids both differentiation and integration: it just uses the notion of limit. Of course, it's totally unmotivated, and you still have to prove that that series actually converges appropriately ...

Comment: @NoahSchweber That is, imo, usually way more advanced than integrating, as it requires limits...and infinite series (which are **not only** limits), and then power or Taylor series, convergence radius and etc.

Comment: "Typically" was maybe the wrong word to use. This is how the function is defined in real analysis. @DonAntonio

Comment: @DonAntonio How are infinite series not only limits? (I don't disagree with your actual point, though - I just wanted to mention that for completeness.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Number series yes...but that doesn't make the cut for power series, which requires quite a bit more than that...though, as usual in calculus, it involves lots of limits.

Comment: @DonAntonio I don't understand your point here. By definition, for **any** sequence of functions $(f_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ and any $x$ we set $\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}f_i(x)$ to be the limit (if it exists) of the sequence of partial sums. What's the missing piece here?

Comment: @NoahSchweber That'd be only pointwise convergence...and it is usually (as far as I am aware) done after studying sequences and number series. In this case, we'd be interested in uniform, absolute and etc. convergence. But anyway: do you know any book that *first* defines the natural logarithm function that way? I don't. There are several good books which use power series to define all kinds of functions: trigonometric, exponential, rational by means of power series...but only after the more usual (for me) basic definitions have been given. This is what I mean here.

Comment: @DonAntonio Of course not, this is a terrible way to introduce $\ln$. But it does work. (Specifically, we ad hoc say: "If $x\in (0,1)$ use such-and-such series, if $x=1$ output $0$, and if $x>1$ take the negative of the first clause applied to $1\over x$." This is a totally accurate definition of $\ln$ ... just awful. And of course its *analysis* takes work, so there's really no point. But strictly speaking it does answer the question: "is it possible to," not "should one" or "does one ever.")

Comment: Well you can do it without the differential calculus (derivative stuff) also. Just define $\log x$ as the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} n(x^{1/ n} - 1)$ where $n$ is a positive integer. A full development of this definition is available on my [blog post](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2014/05/theories-of-exponential-and-logarithmic-functions-part-2_10.html?m=0).

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to define $ln(x)$ without using calculus at all.
You can define $ln(x)$ such that $ln(xy) = ln(x) + ln(y)$, and $ln(e) = 1$. From this definition, all of the properties of $ln(x)$ (like the change of basis formula, being the inverse of $e^x$, and that its deravitive is $\frac{1}{x}$) can be derived.
Unless $x$ is a rational power of $e$, this definition alone doesn't help very much in computing the value of $ln(x)$, but it is rigorous.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to  consider any segment $[c,d]\subset \mathbb{R}$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}, a>1$. As function $f(x)=a^x$ is strictly monotone and continuous, then on segment $[\alpha, \beta],\alpha = a^c, \beta=a^d $ we can define Reverse function $x=f^{-1}(y)$, which we call logarithm $y=\log_a x$.

Answer (score 0):

You could define

$$\ln(a)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{a^h-1}{h}=\left[\frac{d}{dx}a^x\right]_{x=0}$$

Of course, this requires proving the existence of $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{a^h-1}{h}$ for all $a>0$. This definition also assumes that you have adequately defined $a^h$ for all real $h$. One way to do this is to define $a^{(\cdot)}$ as the unique function satisfying these three properties:

1. $a^{(\cdot)}$ is anywhere-continuous (i.e. it is continuous at some point)
2. $a^1=a$
3. $a^{x+y}=a^x a^y$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$

The first property is necessary for $a^{(\cdot)}$ to be continuous everywhere.